# Failed To load JSON Data

Tags: c#, json, mono, xamarin

I am attempting to get JSON from the Instagram API and put the names of the people on my timeline to be on a UITableView using Xamarin.iOS. I am attempting to use JSON.Net and Restsharp to do this, however this problem was never solved for the past few weeks. Here is how I am attempting to retrieve my data, the problem with this is that has an error message: System.InvalidCastexception has been thrown cannot cast from source type to destination type.

On top of this how would I load a specific element onto the table?

I have changed it to `JObject.Parse(response.content);`
and now I receive this error:
[image]
here is my updated code:

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
                var array = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                foreach (JObject obj in array)  
                    {       
                        var Name = (string)obj["data"]["user"]["full_name"];
                        var Caption = (string)obj["data"]["caption"]["text"];
                        var picURL = (string)obj["data"]["images"]["low_resolution"]["url"];

                        System.Console.WriteLine("Name of " + Name + ", Caption of " + Caption + ", and picurl of " + picURL);
                    } 
            });
```

Here is the JSON Response:

```
{
    "pagination": {
        "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=6489401.88b3fb2.7af2a0355ea24f4590efa1ee82ed0a49&max_id=668439962408115415_16915182",
        "next_max_id": "668439962408115415_16915182"
    },
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "attribution": null,
            "tags": [
                "selfie"
            ],
            "type": "image",
            "location": null,
            "comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "data": []
            },
            "filter": "Normal",
            "created_time": "1393953134",
            "link": "http://instagram.com/p/lIO1_jmkkr/",
            "likes": {
                "count": 14,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "username": "muahjay",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_304620904_75sq_1392618687.jpg",
                        "id": "304620904",
                        "full_name": "Jeanettee Nicole Cambero Gamez"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "iam_mrsmith31",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_32806209_75sq_1392607367.jpg",
                        "id": "32806209",
                        "full_name": "Kiondrix Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "anniyalation",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_30752906_75sq_1390523572.jpg",
                        "id": "30752906",
                        "full_name": "Niya G."
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "fonzo_badmon",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_271402803_75sq_1393641486.jpg",
                        "id": "271402803",
                        "full_name": "Slimshady"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "images": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/e02592b0a3bf11e3b63212d269f676eb_6.jpg",
                    "width": 306,
                    "height": 306
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/e02592b0a3bf11e3b63212d269f676eb_5.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/e02592b0a3bf11e3b63212d269f676eb_8.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
            },
            "users_in_photo": [],
            "caption": {
                "created_time": "1393953134",
                "text": "#Selfie",
                "from": {
                    "username": "kthompkins7",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_5941681_75sq_1378508674.jpg",
                    "id": "5941681",
                    "full_name": "kthompkins7"
                },
                "id": "668849828018145517"
            },
            "user_has_liked": false,
            "id": "668849827690989867_5941681",
            "user": {
                "username": "kthompkins7",
                "website": "",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_5941681_75sq_1378508674.jpg",
                "full_name": "kthompkins7",
                "bio": "",
                "id": "5941681"
            }
        },
        {
            "attribution": null,
            "tags": [
                "rp",
                "amen"
            ],
            "type": "image",
            "location": null,
            "comments": {
                "count": 5,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393949795",
                        "text": "@tmcmc Dobson a Christian!!!!",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "keelanwillison",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_26089241_75sq_1380511035.jpg",
                            "id": "26089241",
                            "full_name": "Keelanwillison"
                        },
                        "id": "668821819276579152"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393950029",
                        "text": "Yo my cousin got me a signed autograph from you at the Boston boat show thanks man  @a_dobson3",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "danthebigboy914",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_27354625_75sq_1393859632.jpg",
                            "id": "27354625",
                            "full_name": "Danny Chiappetta"
                        },
                        "id": "668823778033324461"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393950659",
                        "text": "Amen",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "sandyrodr",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_44889389_75sq_1361591427.jpg",
                            "id": "44889389",
                            "full_name": "sandyrodr"
                        },
                        "id": "668829062428545715"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393950664",
                        "text": "",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "cherydaily",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_18483862_75sq_1379884114.jpg",
                            "id": "18483862",
                            "full_name": "Andrew \"Drew\" Chery"
                        },
                        "id": "668829109488636596"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393951921",
                        "text": "Amen",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "bostonsonia",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_182219303_75sq_1391293289.jpg",
                            "id": "182219303",
                            "full_name": "Sonia"
                        },
                        "id": "668839648625348773"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "filter": "Normal",
            "created_time": "1393949714",
            "link": "http://instagram.com/p/lIIUdggtOj/",
            "likes": {
                "count": 324,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "username": "bwest05",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_387702554_75sq_1393739891.jpg",
                        "id": "387702554",
                        "full_name": "bb"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "babygirl6193",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_23365060_75sq_1384972330.jpg",
                        "id": "23365060",
                        "full_name": "babygirl6193"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "derekmooney1",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_218356294_75sq_1388601101.jpg",
                        "id": "218356294",
                        "full_name": "Derek Mooney"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "zay0613",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_342812999_75sq_1369576584.jpg",
                        "id": "342812999",
                        "full_name": "Zay"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "images": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/0e1b270aa3b811e395af12cdc849cb9b_6.jpg",
                    "width": 306,
                    "height": 306
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/0e1b270aa3b811e395af12cdc849cb9b_5.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage11.s3.amazonaws.com/0e1b270aa3b811e395af12cdc849cb9b_8.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
            },
            "users_in_photo": [],
            "caption": {
                "created_time": "1393949714",
                "text": "#RP from @flashgoodwin #AMEN",
                "from": {
                    "username": "a_dobson3",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_203045179_75sq_1374262647.jpg",
                    "id": "203045179",
                    "full_name": "a_dobson3"
                },
                "id": "668821135462420769"
            },
            "user_has_liked": false,
            "id": "668821135110099875_203045179",
            "user": {
                "username": "a_dobson3",
                "website": "",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_203045179_75sq_1374262647.jpg",
                "full_name": "a_dobson3",
                "bio": "",
                "id": "203045179"
            }
        },
        {
            "attribution": null,
            "tags": [
                "tb12"
            ],
            "type": "image",
            "location": null,
            "comments": {
                "count": 169,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393952642",
                        "text": "My guy! The greatest! I just want him to get another ring so the haters can stop saying he hasn't won one since 04. I mean he still won them right? #TomBrady @patriots",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "k_aus32",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_39840771_75sq_1390431094.jpg",
                            "id": "39840771",
                            "full_name": "k_aus32"
                        },
                        "id": "668845703585318559"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393952673",
                        "text": "@heres_jonni9",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "allyson21lautner",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_184895764_75sq_1393107648.jpg",
                            "id": "184895764",
                            "full_name": "Allyson "
                        },
                        "id": "668845962264823470"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393952694",
                        "text": "Let's go !",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "tom12terrific",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_421023272_75sq_1393644166.jpg",
                            "id": "421023272",
                            "full_name": "Andrew Estrada"
                        },
                        "id": "668846135581853361"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393952856",
                        "text": "♡",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "in_neverland74",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_181245582_75sq_1391928288.jpg",
                            "id": "181245582",
                            "full_name": "Karen"
                        },
                        "id": "668847491935880949"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393952914",
                        "text": "Follow for patriots pics daily!! (Ifollowback)",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "ne_patriots_fanpage__",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_983242248_75sq_1391989748.jpg",
                            "id": "983242248",
                            "full_name": "New England Patriots Fanpage"
                        },
                        "id": "668847980295472912"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393952952",
                        "text": "Best ever; period.  Let's see anyone win a ring with the humps he's had to work with, (except Randy).",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "calidoso76",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1101426299_75sq_1392654362.jpg",
                            "id": "1101426299",
                            "full_name": "calidoso76"
                        },
                        "id": "668848301545604900"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393953005",
                        "text": "Shit just because brady hasn't won a ring since 04 don't mean a thing....one more and he'll have 6.....the most superbowl wins than ANY quarterback EVER. @patriots",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "inkandartsosick",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_260242163_75sq_1363337609.jpg",
                            "id": "260242163",
                            "full_name": "Eric Hughes"
                        },
                        "id": "668848744304723771"
                    },
                    {
                        "created_time": "1393953023",
                        "text": "",
                        "from": {
                            "username": "bvsed_papi_",
                            "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_408657565_75sq_1393905141.jpg",
                            "id": "408657565",
                            "full_name": "Abel Valle™"
                        },
                        "id": "668848894913791811"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "filter": "Lo-fi",
            "created_time": "1393949267",
            "link": "http://instagram.com/p/lIHd-_v8Uj/",
            "likes": {
                "count": 13685,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "username": "dollathebarber",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_219503241_75sq_1373905843.jpg",
                        "id": "219503241",
                        "full_name": "dollathebarber"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "emastro23",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_21122956_75sq_1388823730.jpg",
                        "id": "21122956",
                        "full_name": "Eddie Mastrocola"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "pat_fan99",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_304601453_75sq_1377084414.jpg",
                        "id": "304601453",
                        "full_name": "Timothy Smith"
                    },
                    {
                        "username": "___adam___q",
                        "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_3694047_75sq_1367384028.jpg",
                        "id": "3694047",
                        "full_name": "Adam Quinonez"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "images": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c67f514a3b711e383121299eef1f922_6.jpg",
                    "width": 306,
                    "height": 306
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c67f514a3b711e383121299eef1f922_5.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/1c67f514a3b711e383121299eef1f922_8.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
            },
            "users_in_photo": [],
            "caption": {
                "created_time": "1393949267",
                "text": "#tb12",
                "from": {
                    "username": "patriots",
                    "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1939080_75sq_1385924433.jpg",
                    "id": "1939080",
                    "full_name": "New England Patriots"
                },
                "id": "668817391815214218"
            },
            "user_has_liked": false,
            "id": "668817391496447267_1939080",
            "user": {
                "username": "patriots",
                "website": "",
                "profile_picture": "http://images.ak.instagram.com/profiles/profile_1939080_75sq_1385924433.jpg",
                "full_name": "New England Patriots",
                "bio": "",
                "id": "1939080"
            }
        },
        {
            "attribution": null,
            "videos": {
                "low_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/2cb7114aa3b511e3a3e312f545262070_102.mp4",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "standard_resolution": {
                    "url": "http://distilleryimage4.s3.amazonaws.com/2cb7114aa3b511e3a3e312f545262070_101.mp4",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 640
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what line is throwing the exception?

Comment: var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(response.Content);

Comment: Try parsing the content instead

Comment: have you tried just using JObject.Parse()?

Comment: Can you post the JSon (ie response.Content) please.

Comment: @Askolein I have posted the JSON Response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your JSON response (I have updated it for validation purpose from [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)), it seems that the json data is an object type instead of array type. So, after proper classification of your JSON response, your updated code may again be *updated* as below:

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
    {
        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
        foreach (Datum obj in rootObject.data)
        {
            var Name = obj.user.full_name;
            var Caption = obj.caption.text;
            var picURL = obj.images.low_resolution.url;

            System.Console.WriteLine("Name of " + Name + ", Caption of " + Caption + ", and picurl of " + picURL);
        }
    }
);
```

And the classes which you may derive from your JSON response like below have been generated from [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com)

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public object attribution { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public object location { get; set; }
    public Comments comments { get; set; }
    public string filter { get; set; }
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public Likes likes { get; set; }
    public Images images { get; set; }
    public List<object> users_in_photo { get; set; }
    public Caption caption { get; set; }
    public bool user_has_liked { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public Videos videos { get; set; }
}

public class Videos
{
    public LowResolution2 low_resolution { get; set; }
    public StandardResolution2 standard_resolution { get; set; }
}

public class StandardResolution2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class LowResolution2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
    public string bio { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Caption
{
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public LowResolution low_resolution { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    public StandardResolution standard_resolution { get; set; }
}

public class StandardResolution
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class LowResolution
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Likes
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Datum2> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum2
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string profile_picture { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string full_name { get; set; }
}

public class Comments
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<object> data { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class Pagination
{
    public string next_url { get; set; }
    public string next_max_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help! But one last thing, how would I display this onto a UITableView? All the existing code has worked BTW.

Comment: you are also welcome! great to know that it worked for you. BTW, you can start a separate thread with your new query so that you may get your desired answer quickly. good luck!

Comment: @Askolein you are also welcome. You can also try [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) for json validation and indentation formatting.